# Why can't I make a vhd that can open in 7zip?

Tags: imaging

I am trying to create an image for diskless boot using Win 10.

When I finished setting up a client PC (with Win 10), I tried to image it using 1) DD for Windows and 2) Disk2Vhd, now for some reason, the image used by the two tools are not read by 7zip correctly (I currently don't know why).

When I try to open normal vhd files, they can be opened by 7zip, (with the folder structure as shown), but when I try the images created by the 2 tools above, it just displays a blank window (no folder structured detected).

I can give the command line to DD but Disk2Vhd is a GUI tool, so no command line in there, I just include the whole drive c:. Windows drive c: was formatted as MBR partition.

The versions of Disk2Vhd I used were 1.63, 2.01 and 2.02. I also included the system reserved partition in imaging.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?